# Como passar um parâmetro de uma stored procedure com caracteres escapados?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou usando php e mysql e gostaria de passar o seguinte parâmetro para uma stored procedure

```
$param = "col = '{"video":"<iframe width=\'480\' height=\'600\' src=\'www.qualquercoisa.com\´"}'";

call spActCol($param);
```

mas acontece que a stored procedure anula todos os caracteres escapados o que cria um erro quando tenta fazer um atualização na base de dados, ou seja, internamente na procedure a frase fica:

```
UPDATE exemple SET col = '{"video":"<iframe width='480' height='600' src='www.qualquercoisa.com'"}' where id=1;
```

Alguém tem uma ideia como resolver este problema?

Comment: Já tentou colocar src=''www.qualquercoisa.com'' dessa forma? Com duas aspas simples.

Comment: já resolveu o problema ?

Comment: param = "col = '{"video":"<iframe width=\'480\' height=\'600\' src=\'www.qualquercoisa.com\´"}'"; call spActCol(mysql_real_escape_string($param)); A função mysql_real_escape_string vai fazer escape a todas as ' e " de maneira  a que continue a ser uma string. Outra maneira seria fazer queries parametrizadas.

Answer (score 1):

no mysql use:

```
UPDATE exemple SET col = '{"video":"<iframe width=\'480\' height=\'600\' src=\'www.qualquercoisa.com\'"}' where id=1;
```

ou no php use addslashes()

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp

> se esta usando a string para a procedure executar como instrução sql então tem que fazer um prepare/execute
>   exemplo:

```
SET @query = CONCAT("UPDATE exemple SET col = ",@parametro," where id=1");      
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: opa comenta explica ai como a sua procedure esta executando o sql passado como string?